# How to manage multiple sets of system paths for different perspectives in Eclipse

Tags: windows, eclipse, compiler-construction, android-ndk, rcpp

I am working on Windows. In Eclipse, I usually develop Android application with NDK, native c++ application with MingW or Cygwin, or R package with Rcpp.

My problem is that I have to close Eclipse, change system path to corresponding C++ compiler, and restart Eclipse each time when I switch to another. Currently, I have batch files to do that but it's getting messy when other system paths are also added and should be incorporated into the batch files.

Is there any better way to do this?

UPDATE: By searching web, I found [Path Manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pathmanager/) It has a functionality to change path order and I think that will do my purpose.

Comment: Regarding NDK you can use ADT20 or later, and it will define an Android toolchain separate from the native c++ compiler.

Comment: When you install Eclipse with CDT, you have the MinGW and Cygwin toolchains separate. You can choose which to use in "C++ build" dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I tried to reproduce your situation. In eclipse, I have a CDT project. I created it with the standard wizard, and it compiles with Cygwin GCC. I can add a new configuration to this project, call it Android, start with the settings of my Debug configuration, and modify it to use Android GCC and Android Builder. See instructions for [Tool chain editor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_build_toolchain.htm) and [Tool Settings](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_fileprop_toolsettings.htm).

The instructions to define new toolchains are [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/mbs/extensibilityGuide/Managed_Build_Extensibility.html) and [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/cdt_build_system/migration_guides/4.0/migration_guide_40.html)